# Ettus B210 USRP Is it possible to transmit on both Tx Ports either with same or different application?

Tags: gnuradio, transmitter, usrp

Just getting up to speed on the ettus B210 - basically the same as the B200 but with two Rf boards.

I am testing using gnuradio-companion. I have setup a very simple transmitter consisting of:

```
Random Src --> PSK Mod --> UHD USRP Sink (port A:A)
```

This worked fine (I had some frequency / gain sliders). Then I wanted to try to transmit out of both Tx ports, so I tried the following:

```
Random Src --> PSK Mod --> UHD USRP Sink (port A:A, freq - 1MHz)
                   |
                   +-----> UHD USRP Sink (port A:B, freq + 1MHz)
```

It runs, but only port A:A is transmitting and I see loads of "SSSSSSSS"'s in the debug. If I disable either UHD USRP Sink then the other port transmits fine (i.e. I can transmit out of each one individually perfectly.

So how can I send two signals (or the same signal) over both tx port?

Secondly - I want to run two different applications one controlling each port (lets say I run two different gnuradio-companion generated python files each set to different ports)... is this possible? All I got was an error saying that no device was available when I tried to run the second instance, so I guess this may not be possible...

**EDIT**
New simpler setup:

```
sig-src1(samp: 1M) --> USRP Sink (port A:A, freq 1.85G)
sig-src2(samp: 1M) --> USRP Sink (port A:A, freq 1.9G)
```

This is connected directly to a spectrum analyser.

Here is the output I see:

```
Generating: '/home/user/src/gnu-radio/SimpleDualTx.py'

Executing: /usr/bin/python -u /home/user/src/gnu-radio/SimpleDualTx.py

linux; GNU C++ version 5.3.1 20151219; Boost_105800; UHD_003.009.002-0-unknown

-- Detected Device: B210
-- Operating over USB 3.
-- Initialize CODEC control...
-- Initialize Radio control...
-- Performing register loopback test... pass
-- Performing register loopback test... pass
-- Performing CODEC loopback test... pass
-- Performing CODEC loopback test... pass
-- Asking for clock rate 16.000000 MHz... 
-- Actually got clock rate 16.000000 MHz.
-- Performing timer loopback test... pass
-- Performing timer loopback test... pass
-- Setting master clock rate selection to 'automatic'.
-- Asking for clock rate 32.000000 MHz... 
-- Actually got clock rate 32.000000 MHz.
-- Performing timer loopback test... pass
-- Performing timer loopback test... pass
Press Enter to quit: SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
>>> Done (return code -9)
```

This runs, but only port A:B goes into transmit. If I disable either pair of sig-src and USRP Sink the it works fine.

Comment: **Never** use a Throttle block in conjunction with hardware. GRC explicitly has a warning against that.

Comment: You can't tune the TX to two frequencies that are this far apart - there's only one TX mixer for both channels

Comment: Also, try with a different USB port. This looks like your USB 3 controller is dropping packets; for 2x 1MS/s you don't need usb3, a USB 2 would do. Also, just simply set the USRP sink to 2 channels and don't explicitly set the subdevice specification (what you call "port")

Comment: @MarcusMüller ah, ok I can setup a 2-channel USRP sink which takes the two signals. Both transmitter lights now come on. I still struggle to get two distinct signals with any useful seperation - but I am starting to think that (since you mentioned there is only one mixer) the two RF paths are not meant to be separate and distinct. I think what I am trying to do really probably needs 2 x B210  (or B200) boards... would you agree with that? (Note: the USB2 port gave same result - but I think this setup was probably invalid)

Comment: Since you're not telling us **what** you're trying to do in the bigger picture, I have no clue.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Good point - will update that. But essentially I am trying to make two separate transmitters that can transmit at any frequency / waveform independent of each other... now starting to feel that this is not what the two rf paths are for in the USRP B210 - I had though they where completely seperate (hence the cost is ~double of B200), but its probably just for applications like MIMO and such...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UHD requires a USRP to be owned by *one* process only, so no, you can't share the same USRP across two flow graphs, but you could use for example the ZeroMQ PUB/SUB sink/source pair to stream data in from a second application to your first flow graph. But then again, there's nothing wrong with putting a whole flow graph into a hier block¹ and using that in another flow graph.

Also: Throttle is **never** right in a flow graph with hardware. You've got a device with a physical sampling rate to limit how much your computer produces. If you now add a software throttle, either that throttle is useless, or it does harm. That's why we (as in: I personally) added a very prominent warning to GRC that you shouldn't be having a hardware sink and a Throttle block in the same flow graph. Read the console output in the lower half of your GRC window!

¹ hier block: hierarchical block. See the tutorials (in order!) on http://tutorials.gnuradio.org

Comment: The throttle was not having an effect - but I have removed it. I do read the output window, but because I was getting other issues I had missed that, so thanks for picking up on that. So I am still struggling to get two signals out of the USRP (one from each port). So I understand that I can't run two apps - but how do I get two signal out (one from each port)? - example 2 (modified to remove throttle) still does not work - I see loads of "SSSS"'s.... can't figure out how to move on, thanks

Comment: I added an edit with a perhaps more correct / simple example... still no joy though : (

Comment: Marked up as answer, because I think what I am trying to do requires two B200's, but this has provided the information I needed to move on. Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

B210 over USB with stock UHD image can't act like that. Port A is for standard use which is controlled over USB, port B could be used with written custom program inside FPGA. BTW search some info about FULL DUPLEX mode in Open BTS project as for example.